Can monks use Psychic Blades as monk weapons, and do they benefit from monk unarmed damage scaling?
I'm building a Monk/Rogue multiclass character and looking to use the Soulknife’s Psychic Blades to strengthen the monk’s ranged options. I have two main questions about how these abilities interact:
Do Psychic Blades count as Monk weapons? If so, can they benefit from the scaling Martial Arts Die for Monk weapons, including the potential bonus action attack?
Psychic Blades Overview

You can manifest shimmering blades of psychic energy. Whenever you
take the Attack action or make an Opportunity Attack, you can manifest
a Psychic Blade in your free hand and make the attack with that blade.

Key traits of the Psychic Blades:

Weapon Category: Simple Melee
Damage: 1d6 Psychic plus the ability
modifier used for the attack roll
Properties: Finesse, Thrown (60/120
ft range)
Mastery: Vex (doesn’t count against Weapon Mastery limit)
Additional Mechanics: The blade vanishes immediately after it hits or misses its target, and it leaves no mark if it deals damage.
After you attack with the blade on your turn, you can make a melee or ranged attack with a second psychic blade as a Bonus Action on the same turn if your other hand is free to create it. The damage die of this bonus attack is 1d4 instead of 1d6.

Monk’s Martial Arts Ability

Your practice of martial arts gives you mastery of combat styles that
use your Unarmed Strike and Monk weapons, which are the following:
Simple Melee weapons and Martial Melee weapons that have the Light property.

The Martial Arts ability offers these benefits:

Martial Arts Die: Allows you to roll a Monk-specific die in place of
normal damage for Unarmed Strikes or Monk weapons. This die scales as
you level up.

Psychic Blades meet the criteria of a Monk weapon because they are Simple Melee weapons. So, theoretically, they could qualify for the Monk’s Martial Arts Die, scaling with the Monk’s level. For example:
At Rogue 3 / Monk 10, with the Extra Attack feature, you could make two attacks with Psychic Blades, dealing 1d8 + Dexterity modifier each. With both hands free, you could also make a bonus action attack with the second Psychic Blade.
My question here: Is the damage for the bonus action attack fixed at 1d4, or does it scale with the Martial Arts Die if we treat the Psychic Blade as a Monk weapon?
Rules Interpretation: Specific Over General
I understand the “specific over general” rule for interpreting abilities. However, in this case, both abilities could apply as specific:
The rule states the bonus action attack deals 1d4 damage “instead of 1d6.”
Yet, since the Psychic Blade would still meet all requirements as a Monk weapon, it could theoretically qualify for the Monk’s Martial Arts Die.
In this case, does the specific 1d4 damage die override the Monk's specific scaling Martial Arts Die, or can the Martial Arts Die still apply?

Yes
The rogue's Psychic Blades are simple melee weapons and thus qualify as monk weapons. You're correct that the damage die for the Psyhcic Blades' bonus action attack is 1d4, but the Monk's Martial Arts feature lets you use your Martial Arts Die in place of the normal damage of your monk weapons.
Do note, however, that Psychic Blades does not mesh well with Extra Attack. The blade disappears after it hits or misses, and you can only summon it when you take the Attack Action. So after the first attack, the blade vanishes and you can't use it for the second attack. This is discussed here for the 2014 version, but the 2024 version is the same.

Note that they did fix one major problem with the old Soulknife: You can now use the blades for opportunity attacks, which the old version did not allow (it only let you use them for the Attack action, with an optional Bonus Action use).
